# lock/unlock orientation

Tags: android, orientation, flags

To lock my orientation to portrait, I use:
**activity.setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);**
I'm unsure what flag tells the activity to go back to relying on the device orientation.  I imagine it is one of these:
**SCREEN_ORIENTATION_FULL_SENSOR

SCREEN_ORIENTATION_SENSOR

SCREEN_ORIENTATION_UNSPECIFIED

SCREEN_ORIENTATION_USER**

On another note, why isn't the android documentation open source?  The documentation is completely lacking.  Very few of the functions and flags have useful descriptions.

Comment: Regarding your additional note: I found this by clicking through, from http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#setRequestedOrientation%28int%29 to the 'orientation constant as used in' to the meanings of the constants.

Comment: Yeah, and I was on that page and clicked the ActivityInfo.screenOrientation link before making this post.  The next page is completely useless unless you again click "screenOrientation", which gives the actual description of the flags.  I don't understand why clicking one of the flags on the "ActivityInfo.screenOrientation" page doesn't provide an explanation of it.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Per http://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.attr.html#screenOrientation (screenOrientation being what those values are linked to if you dig through the documentation), `SCREEN_ORIENTATION_SENSOR` or `SCREEN_ORIENTATION_FULL_SENSOR` will do it, depending on how much flexibility you want -- however, I suspect what you really want is to go back to the default setting, which is `SCREEN_ORIENTATION_UNSPECIFIED` so that it goes back to the system defaults, including any the user set.

Comment: Thanks.  I guess I failed to click the "screenOrientation" link a second time to take me to the actual attribute page.

Comment: I think it actually took me three or four clicks to get there, so I understand your annoyance.

Answer (score 1):

An easy fix for this that worked for me is to add a line to AndroidManifest.xml like so:

Add android:screenOrientation="portrait"> in the application section.

```
<application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name">
    <activity android:name=".App"
              android:label="@string/app_name"
              android:screenOrientation="portrait">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

</application>
```

Comment: in the ACTIVITY section, not the Application section.

Answer (score 0):

> > If the "`android:immersive"`attribute is set to"`true` " in the app's `manifest entry`for this activity, the `ActivityInfo.flags`member always has its FLAG_IMMERSIVE bit set, even if the immersive mode is changed at runtime using the "`setImmersive()`"  method.